# Change bottom navigation current index and update setState() from another screen class

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bottomnavigationview

Here is my bottom_bar screen. I want to change the bottom navigation menu from another screen button click. How can I resolve this problem?. is there any option that can navigate bottom_navigation from another class. I didn't get any accurate answers through search.
**[N.B: I am totally new in flutter. Please forgive me if there is any type of misconception ]**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeNotifier = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    return  Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('JoyList'),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon:  Image( image: new AssetImage("images/Logo.png"),
                width:  200,
                height: 200,
                color: null,
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
              onPressed: () {
                // scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
              },
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const ImageIcon( AssetImage("images/ic_notification_default.png")),
                tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
                onPressed: () {
                  // scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                },
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: _apiProvider.getUserImageUrl(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> projectSnap) {
                    if(projectSnap.hasData){
                      var url = projectSnap.data;
                      return   IconButton(
                        icon: Center(
                          child: new Container(
                            width: 30,
                            height: 30,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: new DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    image: new NetworkImage(
                                        '$url'
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: _modalBottomSheetMenu,

                      );
                    }else{
                      return Text("Nil");
                    }

                  }
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: CustomNavigator(
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            home: Center(
              child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
            ),
            //Specify your page route [PageRoutes.materialPageRoute] or [PageRoutes.cupertinoPageRoute]
            pageRoute: PageRoutes.cupertinoPageRoute,
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
                canvasColor: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
                // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
                textTheme: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))),
         // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
            child: new BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: selectedIndex,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: selectedIndex==0? new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_home_selected.png')):new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_home_default.png')),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: selectedIndex==1? new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_list_selected.png')):new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_list_default.png')),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: ImageIcon( AssetImage("images/ic_additems.png")),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: ImageIcon( AssetImage("images/ic_search.png")),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: selectedIndex==4? new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_notification_selected.png')):new ImageIcon( AssetImage('images/ic_notification_default.png')),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  //  icon: ImageIcon( AssetImage("images/ic_friends_selected.png")),
                  icon: ImageIcon( AssetImage("images/ic_friends_selected.png")),
                  title: Text(''),
                ),
              ],

              showSelectedLabels: false,
              unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              selectedItemColor: HexColor("1CD0A8"),
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ),
          )
      );

  }
```

I want to change bottom bar selected index from another screen from here on Tap.

```
child:   GestureDetector(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: _getUser(),
                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> projectSnap) {
                          if(projectSnap.hasData){
                            user = projectSnap.data;
                            var url = getProfileImageBaseUrl()+ user.profilePicture;
                            return  Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width: 170,
                                  height: 170,
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      image: new DecorationImage(
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          image: new NetworkImage(
                                              '$url'
                                          )
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

                                    child: Text(user.fullName+"'s List",style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
                                        fontSize: 26
                                    ),),
                                  ),
                                )

                              ],
                            );
                          }else{
                            return Text("Nil");
                          }

                        }
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      print("On tap called");

                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FriendsPage()));
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: I assume the widget is somwhere in the `body` of your `Scaffold`. You could pass the function `_onItemTapped` to the child widget and then call it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MobX](https://mobx.netlify.app/getting-started) for this,
You need to wrap your `BottomNavigationBar` with `Observer` and also declare your `selectedIndex` in [MobX](https://mobx.netlify.app/getting-started) store.

Once you have `selectedIndex` in your MobX store you can access it from anywere in app using `Provider`.