# How to change the value in static list from another page in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter

### SITUATION

static list in `FirstScreen.dart`

```
static List<Shoe> shoeBank = [
    Shoe(iN:0,b: "Red Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct1.jpg", q: 0,c: Color(0xFFC60635)),
    Shoe(iN:1,b: "White Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct2.jpg", q: 0, c: Colors.white)
  ];
```

### Explanation

I am changing one of the item value`int`from `ThirdScreen.dart` in the list. It does change in the `list` but does not show the updated value in the `SecondScreen.dart`screen? However, when I go back all the way to `FirstScreen.dart` then it does show the updated value in the second screen.

### Tried

I have tried using SetState in the ThirdScreen.dart while updating the value.

### Question

*How to make the `SecondScreen.dart` show the updated value when came back from `ThirdScreen.dart` and what might went wrong?

Comment: Can U add the code of both dart files?

Comment: Some situation occured, by the way there are 3 screen. list is in the second screen. When updated the value from third screen, it updates the value in list but when came back to the second screen, it does not show the updated value in the screen.
However, when I go back to the first screen and then to the second screen, second screen does show the updated value in the screen.

Comment: You can use MobX for this solution, Your second screen does not get update event when you change value in static variables,
Please see this answer in detail to understand MobX properly Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63072502/11445644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With provider package (RECOMMENDED!)

As Nour already pointed out you should make a Model class which holds your `List<Shoe>`. A `static` variable to store some changing data is never the way you should go.

The steps I would recommend are the following:

1. Create a model class like `ShoeStore` which extends `ChangeNotifier`
2. In this class you store you `List<Shoe>` and you write your methods to change this list. Important is that at the end of the methods you call `notifyListeners`.
3. As the parent of your `MaterialApp` you create a `MultiProvider` widget where you initialize the `ShoeStore`
4. There, where you need to access the `ShoeStore` you provide the widget `Cosumer<ShoeStore>`. And instead of a child you insert your children there in a `builder` property which gets the `ShoeStore` instance as an argument.
5. Read this [great guide!](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) about Statemanagement with Provider for Flutter.

This is how your code could look like:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              ShoeStore([Shoe(name: "Nike"), Shoe(name: "Adidas")]),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: FirstScreen()),
            Expanded(child: SecondScreen()),
            Expanded(child: ThirdScreen())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 100,
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ShoeStore>(
      builder: (context, shoeStore, child) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: 100,
        child: Text("Number of shoes: ${shoeStore.shoes.length}",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ShoeStore>(
      builder: (context, shoeStore, child) => Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 100,
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            "Add Shoe",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          onPressed: () => shoeStore.addShoe(Shoe(name: "Bugatti")),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShoeStore extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Shoe> _shoes;

  ShoeStore(List<Shoe> initialValue) {
    _shoes = initialValue;
  }

  List<Shoe> get shoes => _shoes;

  void addShoe(Shoe shoe) {
    _shoes.add(shoe);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Shoe {
  String name;
  Shoe({this.name});
}
```

As you can see. The `FirstScreen` is now empty and you do not have to store you List there anymore.

## Without any package (NOT RECOMMENDED!!!!)

Without any package I would inject the `State` of my App into the Widgets which have to read or write the fields of the state.

This would look like:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Shoe> _shoes = [Shoe(name: "Nike"), Shoe(name: "Adidas")];

  void addShoe(Shoe shoe) => setState(() {
    _shoes.add(shoe);
  });

  List<Shoe> get shoes => _shoes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: FirstScreen()),
          Expanded(child: SecondScreen(this)),
          Expanded(child: ThirdScreen(this))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 100,
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyAppState appState;

  SecondScreen(this.appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 100,
      child: Text("Number of shoes: ${appState.shoes.length}",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyAppState appState;

  ThirdScreen(this.appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      color: Colors.green,
      height: 100,
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          "Add Shoe",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        onPressed: () => appState.addShoe(Shoe(name: "Bugatti")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Shoe {
  String name;
  Shoe({this.name});
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest a solution without using any packages?

Comment: Sure, I can add this. But I really DON'T RECOMMEND this. Is there a reason why you don't want to use the provider package?

Comment: I am an intern and I need to understand the basic behind the state management

Comment: I added it. But again: I really don't recommend this. You can try it out, but please stick to Provider or any other State Management framework. Otherwise the second approach will kill your mind as soon as your app reached some complexity.

Answer (score 3):

For a **clean** solution you need to make `Store` class that holds the list along with the list manipulation methods, then use a `provider` package for example to listen to all the changes that happens to the list.

Here is a small example:

```
class Store extends ChangeNotifier {
  var myList = <String>[];

  void add() {
    myList.add('new item');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageNumber = 1;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Store(),
          child: pageNumber == 1 ? FirstPage() : SecondPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var store = Provider.of<Store>(context);
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () => store.add()),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var store = Provider.of<Store>(context);

    return Column(
      children: [
        ...store.myList.map((item) => Text(item)).toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read my updated question, I did not get your answer properly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need a 'state management' package like: provider, mobx, ...etc to do what you want to achieve in a clean manner, because a `static` list isn't the right way to do it =D